# Using a hashtable for locking on individual database rows

Tags: .net, locking, blocking

I'm trying to handle locks for a nonstandard database (i.e. it doesn't provide this functionality itself). My program has exclusive access to the db, but there are multiple concurrent threads that need to be synchronized.

The naive implementation I used before was to lock globally, not allowing parallel accesses to separate rows (which is by design always threadsafe).

To implement this feature, my idea would be to use a common hash table that stores all row ids that are in use right now. Access to this hash table would need to be synchronized, typically via locking on it.

However, if we find that the row we want to use is already in use, we have to wait for it to be released. This is not entirely trivial, my guess would be to use a signal to wait.

I'm not sure how exactly to do this, though. Can you think of a good way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You idea of using a hash-table item per row is good. As the value in this hash-table I'd store a lock for this particular row. Any thread wanting to access a row would retrieve (or create) the corresponding lock in this hash-table first. Then it would take the lock and later release it.

It is important that all access to the global hash-table is very quick. Having a lock object per row addresses that goal because once you retrieved the lock object you can unlock the hash-table immediately no matter how long your operation will last.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this naive implementation.

```
internal class LockingTest
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ReaderWriterLockSlim> _Locks = new Dictionary<string, ReaderWriterLockSlim> ();

    private void LockRow (string id)
    {
        ReaderWriterLockSlim slim;

        for (; ; ) {
            lock (_Locks) {
                /*
                 * if row not in use, grab it
                 */
                if (!_Locks.TryGetValue (id, out slim)) {
                    slim = new ReaderWriterLockSlim (); // this can probably be replaced by a different, cheap signal class
                    slim.EnterWriteLock ();
                    _Locks.Add (id, slim);
                    return;
                }
            }

            /*
             * row is in use, wait until released, then try again
             */
            slim.EnterWriteLock ();
        }
    }

    private void UnlockRow (string id)
    {
        /*
         * release and remove lock
         */
        lock (_Locks) {
            var slim = _Locks[id];
            _Locks.Remove (id);
            slim.ExitWriteLock ();
        }
    }

    public void Test ()
    {
        var rnd = new Random ();

        Action thread = () => {
            for (; ; ) {
                var id = rnd.NextDouble () < 0.5 ? "a" : "b";

                Console.WriteLine (Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " waits for " + id);
                LockRow (id);
                Console.WriteLine (Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " locked " + id);
                Thread.Sleep (rnd.Next (0, 100));

                UnlockRow (id);
                Console.WriteLine (Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " released " + id);
                Thread.Sleep (rnd.Next (0, 100));
            }
        };

        new Thread (() => thread ()) {
            Name = "L1",
            IsBackground = true
        }.Start ();

        new Thread (() => thread ()) {
            Name = "L2",
            IsBackground = true
        }.Start ();

        Thread.Sleep (1000);
    }
```

Output

```
L1 waits for a
L1 locked a
L2 waits for b
L2 locked b
L2 released b
L1 released a
L1 waits for a
L1 locked a
L2 waits for a
L1 released a
L2 locked a
L2 released a
L1 waits for b
L1 locked b
L2 waits for b
L1 released b
L2 locked b
L1 waits for a
L1 locked a
L2 released b
L1 released a
L1 waits for a
L1 locked a
L2 waits for a
L1 released a
L2 locked a
L1 waits for b
L1 locked b
L1 released b
L2 released a
L1 waits for b
L1 locked b
L1 released b
L2 waits for a
L2 locked a
L2 released a
L1 waits for b
L1 locked b
L2 waits for a
L2 locked a
L2 released a
L1 released b
L1 waits for b
L1 locked b
L1 released b
L2 waits for a
L2 locked a
L1 waits for a
L2 released a
L1 locked a
L2 waits for b
L2 locked b
L1 released a
L1 waits for b
L2 released b
L1 locked b
L1 released b
```

Comment: updated source code including global locks in addition to local locks see https://github.com/mafutrct/Zysl/blob/master/trunk/Zysl/Utils/BlockingSet.cs